# After setting fish shell default all commands are unknown

Tags: command-line, tty, fish

After I set fish shell default and rebooting I cannot login (because I am using sddm) and every command that I type in tty are unknown. I don’t know how to fix it.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What commands did you use to make this fish shell the default?

Comment: I used chsh -s $(which fish)

Comment: That was the one and only command. Very strange I was just reading this doc it is a lot more then 1 command. https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-fish-shell-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I followed almost the same tutorial, I used the same commands that they use in this tutorial to setup fish bu I cannot go back to bash because it says that this command is unknown

Comment: use `/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash`. I guess the path is not added correctly in the fish shell.

Comment: Are you saying that every command is `command not found`?  Can you add some examples of exactly what you are seeing in the tty?  Thanks!  (P.S. I'm guessing @Marco is on the right track).

Comment: @Marco it worked, thank you